# Finding ways to root my TWM Amazing X2

Tags: rooting

I want to root my new phone, TWM Amazing X2
But I can't find it anywhere, seriously. So I'm stucked here.
I've tried doing some google-surfing, bing, and all sorts of China softwares to root but none of it returned suceed.

Some infos:

> Phone: Taiwan Mobile Amazing X2 
> Model number: Amazing X2 
> Android
>   version: 4.4.2 
> Kernel: 3.4.0 ZTE-kernel@Zdroid-SMT

Comment: Could you try [Farmaroot](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/framaroot/root-framaroot-one-click-apk-to-root-t2130276)? It supports a lot of devices.

Comment: Tried and it failed. D:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last, I've rooted my phone using the way on http://apk.tw/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=622501&extra=page%3D5

Comment: Can you link to the page/instructions rather than the archive?  Future readers have no context or reason to trust this.

Comment: oops, accidentally pasted the direct link instead of the forum link, didn't see that. Link changed to the original post.